# Determine if block has already been registered

Tags: block-editor

In gutenberg/block-editor, how can I check whether I've already registered a block type? Is there a function I can use? Searching through the Block Editor Handbook I couldn't see a function to check this.

An example of what I am trying to do is below:

```
class My_Block {

    public function __construct() {
        if ( ! SOME_FUNCTION_block_exists('foo/column') ) {
            register_block_type( 'foo/column', my_args );
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: have you encountered problems with blocks being registered multiple times? What's the reason and context behind the question?

Comment: @TomJNowell I haven't tested what happens when a block is registered twice. The reason is for efficiency of code.

Answer (score 3):

****EDIT****

I just realized you're doing this on the PHP side. There is a class called `WP_Block_Type_Registry` that you can use to see what is already registered:

```
$registry = WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance();
if ( ! $registry->get_registered( 'foo/column' ) ) {
    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Gutenberg should fire a console error if a block has already been registered. See the `registerBlockType` src [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/blocks/src/api/registration.js#L247).

Answer (score 0):

When editing a page using Gutenberg, you can use the Developers Console to execute [`wp.blocks.getBlockTypes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-blocks/#getblocktypes) and get all active registered blocks in Gutenberg.

You can also use the [WP_Block_Type_Registry](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_block_type_registry) Class in order get all server-side registered Blocks.
You can than either use [get_all_registered()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_block_type_registry/get_all_registered/) or [get_instance()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_block_type_registry/get_instance/):

```php
WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_all_registered();
```

or

```php
WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered();
```

Both do the same. `get_instance()` returns itself.